# How to archive ONLY read emails in Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How do I archive only 'read' emails in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 2):

I will promptly delete this answer if someone proves it wrong, but I've been wanting to do this for a long time and the short answer is: you can't.

Comment: Say it ain't so :(

Comment: What I've been doing is just flagging the email for followup. When it auto-archives it then still shows in the tasks listing. However if you have a few dozen of them they all get lost in eachother.

Comment: yeah - you can't; the AutoArchive function is based on date - for better or worse

Answer (score 0):

It is a manual process, and is actually more of an organizational method, but I tend to sort mail that I have read, and require no further action into a separate folder. By doing this I can archive this 'done' folder by year. (Or qtr of year in my case)